# Jquery's php "if condition" equivalent

Tags: jquery

I have this php simple if condition:

```
if ( $myvar == '2' || $myvar == '6' || $myvar == '10'){}
```

How can I write this in jquery?

Ty!

I did it like this:

```
if (jQuery.inArray(2,6,10)) { do something }
```

Ty guys!

Comment: Why jquery? Do you mean Javascript? Add more info what do you want to do.

Comment: 1) That was not even valid PHP code, you were missing a closing quote - FTFY; 2) jQuery is a library built on JavaScript; and 3) it would be essentially the same in JavaScript, (the `$` prefix is not required for JS variables, but valid nonetheless).

Comment: This is already literally valid JavaScript code, except for the missing closing quote.

Comment: `jQuery.inArray( value, array [, fromIndex] )` - so, you're searching for `2` in an array of `6` (not even `[6]`), from index `10`? Are you sure the code is doing what you *think* it's supposed to be doing? Y'know, "it works for me" might be for different reasons than you expect. http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With jQuery:

```
if ($.inArray($myvar, ['2','6','10'])) {
    // do something
}
```

But if you stop and remember that jQuery is a library of JavaScript functions and not a language on its own then presumably what you really want is to do it in JavaScript in which case the code from the question is actually valid JS too (once the closing quotation mark is added to `'10`):

```
if ( $myvar == '2' || $myvar == '6' || $myvar == '10'){}
```

Comment: Thank you, the first piece of code has an error i think. Can you please check it?

Comment: Just solved it, ty very much. It was just a slight difference in syntax.

Comment: You're welcome. Note: I wasn't really serious about using `$.inArray()` for this purpose - it will work (though you've got the syntax wrong in what you edited into your question), but I'd use the more traditional `if(a || b || c)` syntax from the end of my question.